# Error com.google.android.gms/play-services/8.4.0/ gradle:2.0.0-alpha5

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

After updating the SDK AndroidStudio told me to update to gradle:2.0.0-alpha5. 
When I build/run the app gradle fails and says:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/pepperonas/IdeaProjects/Android/M104/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services/8.4.0/jars/classes.jar (No such file or directory)

Downgrading to gradle:2.0.0-alpha3 will solve it, but I want to use the newest version.

Does any body know how to fix it?

(Note: I use AndroidStudio 2.0 Preview 5)

As always, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found the solution:

Updating will do the trick.

```
'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha9'
```

**UPDATE (2015-02-28)**

alpha9 is available now

**NOTE**

Bookmark this [page](https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/) <- seems to be a MUST for every android-dev. :)

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, you are the not the only one with this issue. There seems to be some bug on the `alpha5` build for the `Gradle` build tools. There is already a ticket created on the Android Bug Tracker.

More info:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=198937

In the meantime `alpha3` build tool is the way to go about. I am doing the same thing as of now until the issue is resolved in the next release.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you do find an workaround, kindly post an answer to your question. Otherwise please close the question by accepting it as appropriate. Thanks!

Comment: @askarcali why? Please check my answer.

Comment: oh sorry dude by mistake i commented here it should be your answer

Answer (score 0):

As per today (9.Mar.2016) `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta6` is available. Update your `project/gradle.build`. Also update gradle distribution  to [2.11-all](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.11-all.zip)

Anyone interested in getting latest build updates view email for `com.android.tools.build:gradle` can go to [bintray](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle/2.0.0-beta6/view) site and subscribe for it.

**Update (9.Mar.2016)**

`com.android.tools.build.gradle 2.1.0-alpha1` has just been released.

Comment: Great comment. But not an answer.

Comment: Great - now _that's_ an answer! Cheers!